# Как сделать слияние двух JS-объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть два JS-объекта, которые мне нужно слить так, чтобы получился либо уже готовый объект, где нет повторяющихся элементов, либо так, чтобы на выходе я получил объект только с теми "ключ: значение", которых нету в каком-то одном объекте, но есть в другом. Для этого есть spread-оператор в ES2018, но он, видимо, делает не слияние двух объектов, а слияние всех ключей и значений второго объекта в первый, что мне не совсем подходит:

```js
let obj1 = {
  obj_nested: {
    obj12: 'value',
    obj13: 'value'
  }
}

let obj2 = {
  obj_nested: {
    obj12: 'value',
    obj14: 'value'
  }
}

let merged = {...obj1, ...obj2}
console.log(merged)
```

Comment: Object.assign()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, Вам подойдет данный метод

[Но следует помнить про распространенность ES6 и IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class)

```js
let obj1 = {
  obj_nested: {
    obj12: 'value',
    obj13: 'value'
  }
}

let obj2 = {
  obj_nested: {
    obj12: 'value',
    obj14: 'value'
  }
}

function deepMerge(...sources) {
  let acc = {}
  for (const source of sources) {
    if (source instanceof Array) {
      if (!(acc instanceof Array)) {
        acc = []
      }
      acc = [...acc, ...source]
    } else if (source instanceof Object) {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(source)) {
        if (value instanceof Object && key in acc) {
          value = deepMerge(acc[key], value)
        }
        acc = { ...acc, [key]: value }
      }
    }
  }
  return acc
}

console.log(deepMerge(obj1, obj2));
```